# Multiple UL, count li inside each

Tags: jquery

I have a page with about 31

```
<ul class="sortableList">
<li>Jargon</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to loop each sortableList and count the number of li inside that ul.

So far I have

```
    _.each($('.sortableList'), function(info, key) {
      console.log($(this).length);
    });
```

However in console I'm getting 31 x 0. Its not counting the li inside each list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to count the *children* of the `<ul>` element, not the element itself.  Also, you don't need underscore.js here.

```
$('.sortableList').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).children('li').length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why underscore `each`. It's more natural to use `$.each`:

```
$('.sortableList').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('li').length);
});
```

or if you just need direct descendant `li`'s count:

```
$('.sortableList').each(function() {
    console.log(this.children.length);
});
```